# How to convert time in ms to GPS location..?

Tags: java, gps, latitude-longitude, gps-time

I have a problem of conversion time in ms to GPS location.
While the car was in drive, sensor will send the Lat and Long, like the following:

```
Lat : -1503044350/ms
Long : 1926596112/ms
```

How to convert this data to get lat and long from google map?

Comment: What APIs are you using? What libraries are you using?

Comment: I dont have any idea of what to do with that data to convert lat and long. What API and libraries are best to use..?

Comment: Do you have a description of the sensor? What is the unit of your values?

Comment: @smartmeta Unit of the values is ms

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the
[Convert between Degree and Miliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311316/convert-between-degree-and-miliseconds)
 SO post, it states

> There are 360 degrees (longitude), 60 minutes per degree, 60 secondes
>   per minute, 1000 milliseconds per second.

And explains how to convert it seconds, minutes and degrees.