# Unknown GPS Format

Tags: format, gps

I've got the following gps data

```
lat
178197561,44201

long
41176829,78193
```

And I'm not able to map this to any gps coordinates. 
The location is somewhere in germany but I don't have an exact location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is milliseconds. To get GPS-coordinates the following python function can be used.

```
from decimal import *
def convert_to_degree(mil):
    return Decimal(mil / (60*60*1000))
```

The comma has to be replaced with a dot beforehand.
For a detailed explanation this post might help 
[Convert between Degree and Milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311316/convert-between-degree-and-milliseconds)